# How can I set a breakpoint whenever a integer*8 variable is converted into integer*4 using gdb?

Tags: fortran, gdb

I am trying to convert a 32bit code to 64 bit. However some variables (addresses of cray pointers) must be declared integer*8 consistently because malloc will return the address as a integer*8 variable.

```
 integer*8 ptr
 ptr = malloc(size)
 getmem(ptr, size)   ! wrapper around malloc hence ptr must be integer*8
```

Beyond this the logic gets convoluted. Somewhere the address as integer*8 is converted to integer*4 but I do not know the location. So I am asking: How can I set a breakpoint/watchpoint whenever a integer*8 variable is converted into integer*4 using gdb?

Comment: I think that making your code Standard Conform by removing those extensions (Cray pointers,...) will make your code portable ( between architectures and OSs ) and modern.

Comment: Can't remove cray pointers. There are 1500 of them and 300-400 share memory

Comment: What do you mean by a variable being converted?  In the example `ptr` is _always_ `integer*8` but its value may be assigned to something not.  You can possibly get your compiler to tell you when there is assignment like this.

Comment: @francescalus, that would be a great idea if I knew how to do that. How can I get my compiler to detect such assignments?

Comment: That would depend on your compiler, but with gfortran you can try `-Wconversion`.

Comment: What about just using default integer of 8?

Comment: It worked but the answer was unphysical